# Are there downsides to using std::string as a buffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

I have recently seen a colleague of mine using `std::string` as a buffer:

```
std::string receive_data(const Receiver& receiver) {
  std::string buff;
  int size = receiver.size();
  if (size > 0) {
    buff.resize(size);
    const char* dst_ptr = buff.data();
    const char* src_ptr = receiver.data();
    memcpy((char*) dst_ptr, src_ptr, size);
  }
  return buff;
}
```

I guess this guy wants to take advantage of auto destruction of the returned string so he needs not worry about freeing of the allocated buffer.

This looks a bit **strange** to me since according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) the `data()` method returns a `const char*` pointing to a buffer internally managed by the string:

```
const char* data() const noexcept;
```

**Memcpy-ing to a const char pointer**? AFAIK this does no harm as long as we know what we do, but have I missed something? Is this dangerous?

Comment: With C++17 `data()` has an overload returning a pointer to non-const qualified char.

Comment: ...which is mentioned by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). cplusplus.com is not the best source.

Comment: I think that the operation of casting from `const char*` to `char*` by itself implies some sort of hazard in your program. If `dst_ptr` points to a read-only memory block, then you should not attempt to write into that block using this pointer.

Comment: Whenever you see code using C-style casts (like e.g. `(char*) dst_ptr`) you should take that as a red flag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think that `const_cast` would pass compilation, but the problem wold persist, wouldn't it? Sorry, taking it back (`const_cast` would be used for the opposite casting).

Comment: Just avoid the confusion and use a `vector<char>` instead. Works even prior to C++17.

Comment: For arbitrary data, `std::vector<char>` is a more sensible choice.

Comment: I think this question is mostly opinion-based.  IMO using `std::string` as a buffer is fine if you know you're receiving text data.  If you're receiving binary data `std::vector<char>` is probably a better choice.

Comment: @MilesBudnek intended to use for receiving binary data.

Comment: @goodvibration why do you think the content of a local `std::string` variable might point to read-only memory block? How would `buff[0] = 'a';` work if that was true?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I didn't say any of that. I said that a `const char*` variable could point to a read-only memory region, so casting it to `char*` and then using it in order to write to memory could lead to a memory access violation. Hence the hazard that I have pointed out.

Comment: @goodvibration but the `const char*` comes from a local `std::string` variable. You said "If `dst_ptr` points to a read-only memory block" which it **cannot** in this code, so the comment isn't really relevant to **this code**. Saying "you shouldn't do X because sometimes it's undefined" isn't helpful for the cases which are definitely not undefined.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I was trying to emphasize that a raw cast from `const char*` to `char*` should automatically "raise a flag". You use it in the wrong place and you end up with undefined behavior of your program (which would not necessarily be traceable easily).

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11358879/541686 In particular note the invalidation rules.

Comment: A little on the side: You mentioned your colleague intended to avoid having to worry about freeing the allocated buffer. This shouldn't be relevant in any way you do it. It's 2019. Not matter how you implement it, you should never have to worry about it. Thanks to collections and smart pointers and others.

Comment: When I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDJImePyftY) it looked very promising to me but I never tried.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

### Don't use `std::string` as a buffer.

It is bad practice to use `std::string` as a buffer, for several reasons (listed in no particular order):

- `std::string` was not intended for use as a buffer; you would need to double-check the description of the class to make sure there are no "gotchas" which would prevent certain usage patterns (or make them trigger undefined behavior).
- As a concrete example: Before C++17, you [can't even write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) through the pointer you get with `data()` - it's `const Tchar *`; so your code would cause undefined behavior. (But `&(str[0])`, `&(str.front())`, or `&(*(str.begin()))` would work.)
- Using `std::string`s for buffers is confusing to readers of your function's definition, who assume you would be using `std::string` for, well, strings. In other words, doing so breaks the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187457/63497).
- Worse yet, it's confusing for whoever might *use* your function - they too may think what you're returning is a string, i.e. valid human-readable text.
- [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) would be fine for your case, or even [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). In C++17, you can use [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) for the element type, too. A more sophisticated option is a class with an [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring)-like feature, e.g. Boost's [`small_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html) (thank you, @gast128, for mentioning it).
- (Minor point:) libstdc++ had to change its ABI for `std::string` to conform to the C++11 standard, so in some cases (which by now are rather unlikely), you might run into some linkage or runtime [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571583/understanding-gcc-5s-glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-or-the-new-abi) that you wouldn't with a different type for your buffer.

<sub>Also, your code may make two instead of one heap allocations (implementation dependent): Once upon string construction and another when `resize()`ing. But that in itself is not really a reason to avoid `std::string`, since you can avoid the double allocation using the construction in [@Jarod42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56423071/1593077).</sub>

Comment: And with `std::string_view`, you can *define* readable portions of the buffer.

Comment: @M.M For example the terminating `\0` character which `std::string` guarantees to be present. Would you know off-hand whether it is included in the valid range of `data()`? [Overwriting it is UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)! It needs a few extra mental cycles (and possibly reference lookups) to verify this function does not have UB from that.

Comment: @M.M: The point is - you don't intuitively know! I wasn't even aware of what MaxLanghof wrote in his comment.

Comment: +1 for `std::byte`, unbelievable I haven't heard of it before! It's crazy how often one looks into some C++ reference every day and still new things keep popping up...

Comment: @andreee - Be careful of `std::byte`. It is nothing like a `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`. You can only do a few bit operations on it. You can't add them or use them in math expressions. Also see [std::byte](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Std::byte#Semantic_equivalence) for details of supporting it.

Comment: All true but std::string often have small string optimizations which might a thing if using many buffers with small length. Alternatively one could use basic_string with std::byte as type for these buffers

Comment: @gast128: How does SSO bear on my arguments?

Comment: @einpoklum: I thought it was quite clear. std::vector (and unique_ptr) has worse performance in creation and access when you have a small number of elements compared to std::basic_string with SSO. At least you could mention that. I am also not sure if the standard forbids basic_string to be used as a buffer as in supporting contiguous block of memory.

Comment: @gast128: Oh, you mean using std::string for its SSO as an optimization? I see what you mean, but: 1. We can't rely on that. 2. If performance is so critical, we probably don't want the extra container anyway and you'd pass a reference to `Received`. 3. We can always use a buffer class with a similar optimization.

Comment: @einpoklum: note that it's not only in creation but also in access pattern. With SSO one probably has locality of memory access patterns which modern processors optimize for. boost offers small_vector which is a vector with SSO. Pity that these things don't end up in the std.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: So, this is, in a sense, covered by my first point - but at the same time you're absolutely right. I did not even remember that `data()` provides a `const char*`. See edit.

Comment: `.data()` may only have gained a non-const overload in C++17, but `&str[0]`, `&str.front()`, and `str.begin()` would have worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Fair enough but that's not what OP for using, and you're reinforcing my first point.

Answer (score 66):

You can completely avoid a manual `memcpy` by calling the appropriate constructor:

```
std::string receive_data(const Receiver& receiver) {
    return {receiver.data(), receiver.size()};
}
```

That even handles `\0` in a string.

BTW, unless content is actually text, I would prefer `std::vector<std::byte>` (or equivalent).

Comment: Is `memcpy((char*) dst_ptr, src_ptr, size);` an UB as what @Serge Ballesta claimed?

Comment: As original buffer data should not be not `const`, you should not have UB.

Comment: And by then a good programmer goes: "Why the hell do I need a separate one-liner conversion function? Not only that, but this function named 'receive' doesn't actually perform any 'receiving'. Delete!"

Comment: @screwnut: To be fair, it is theoretically possible that `receiver.data()` waits on the reception to happen, or does something else beyond returning a member pointer.

Comment: @screwnut: Then I'm a bad programmer; I'll keep the conversion in a separate function, even if it's a one liner, because I appreciate abstraction and do not like to repeat myself. If I later need to add some checks, some logging, etc... the function is right here and I don't have to hunt around the codebase for all instances of conversion.

Comment: @einpoklum And in your theoretical world, what does the `size` member do? Let's not kid ourselves that this code reflects poor design to begin with...

Comment: @MatthieuM. There shouldn't be a conversion function at all. There should be a single member function on `Receiver` that returns the data in a sensible `std` container. That's where the abstraction ought to sit. If `Receiver`'s users then want to convert to  any other data type, it's on them. It's not on `Receiver`'s writer to try and guess what different types could users want and provide that many conversion functions. Well, IMHO anyway.

Comment: @screwnut: Prefer non-member non-friend functions.

Comment: @screwnut: It's not my theoretical world, it's OPs. That Receiver class feels suspicious to me, I wouldn't presume to guess exactly how it works.

Comment: This "answer" contains useful guidance on the topic, but it doesn't seem like a response to the question.

Answer (score 10):

> Memcpy-ing to a const char pointer? AFAIK this does no harm as long as we know what we do, but is this good behavior and why?

The current code may have undefined behavior, depending on the C++ version. To avoid undefined behavior in C++14 and below take the address of the first element. It yields a non-const pointer:

```
buff.resize(size);
memcpy(&buff[0], &receiver[0], size);
```

---

> I have recently seen a colleague of mine using `std::string` as a buffer...

That was somewhat common in older code, especially circa C++03. There are several benefits and downsides to using a string like that. Depending on what you are doing with the code, `std::vector` can be a bit anemic, and you sometimes used a string instead and accepted the extra overhead of `char_traits`.

For example, `std::string` is usually a faster container than `std::vector` on append, and you can't return `std::vector` from a function. (Or you could not do so in practice in C++98 because C++98 required the vector to be constructed in the function and copied out). Additionally, `std::string` allowed you to search with a richer assortment of member functions, like `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of`. That was convenient when searching though arrays of bytes.

I think what you really want/need is SGI's [Rope class](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/Rope.html), but it never made it into the STL. It looks like GCC's [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/libstdc++/api/a01520_source.html) may provide it.

---

There a lengthy discussion about this being legal in C++14 and below:

```
const char* dst_ptr = buff.data();
const char* src_ptr = receiver.data();
memcpy((char*) dst_ptr, src_ptr, size);
```

I know for certain it is not safe in GCC. I once did something like this in some self tests and it resulted in a segfault:

```
std::string buff("A");
...

char* ptr = (char*)buff.data();
size_t len = buff.size();

ptr[0] ^= 1;  // tamper with byte
bool tampered = HMAC(key, ptr, len, mac);
```

GCC put the single byte `'A'` in register `AL`. The high 3-bytes were garbage, so the 32-bit register was `0xXXXXXX41`. When I dereferenced at `ptr[0]`, GCC dereferenced a garbage address `0xXXXXXX41`.

The two take-aways for me were, don't write half-ass self tests, and don't try to make `data()` a non-const pointer.

Comment: Prefer `std::copy` for type-safety. It won't be slower.

Comment: Seems like the only answer directly answering the question.

Comment: "you can't return `std::vector` from a function. (Or you could not do so back in C++98 or C++03)" is wrong.

Comment: And it has never been a legal optimization for a compiler to confuse an address with stored content.  `buff.data()` cannot be a register containing `'A'`, it must be an address.

Comment: @Ben - Yeah, I think the problem with `std::vector` in C++98 was the language required the vector to be created in the function and then copied back to the caller. MS compilers did not improve after the restriction was changed (C++03?). I cleaned that up in the answer.

Comment: @Ben - For the segfault, I'm just recounting what I observed when stepping the assembly under a debugger. That was back in 2010 or 2012 or so. I'm guessing the undefined behavior meant all bets were off.

Comment: @jww: Indeed, although you could avoid that copy with NRVO and a `swap()` call.  But the copy would also be required of `std::string`.  Small string optimization could make it a little better.  I think some implementations tried to solve this using copy-on-write (for `string`, never allowed for `vector`) but even in C++98 and C++03 there were some specifications on `std::string` that couldn't be reasonable met by COW.  Of course rvalue references and moves solved it neatly.

Comment: I think this is a good answer but I’m confused as to why appending to `std::string` should be faster than to `std::vector<char>`. Do they have different resizing behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

From C++17, `data` can return a non const `char *`.

Draft n4659 declares at [string.accessors]:

> ```
> const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
> const charT* data() const noexcept;
> ....
> charT* data() noexcept;
> ```

Comment: Well, my question is not tagged with `C++17`. Anyway, good to know what you just pointed out.

Comment: @duong_dajgja: Before C++17 `data` only returned a `const` pointer, so changing its content was formally Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Only if it actually pointed at an object *declared* with the `const` qualifier. Which it doesn't, since `operator[]` can return a non-const reference to a char in that very same buffer (guaranteed since C++11).

Comment: @StoryTeller: I cannot understand your comment. I read `const char* dst_ptr = buff.data();` then `memcpy((char*) dst_ptr, src_ptr, size);`. This removes the `const` qualifier but is still UB before C++17.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Question is tagged appropriately (with C++11) from beginning. (even if I think that it doesn't invalidate answer which specify explicitly version).

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Removing a const qualifier **is not** UB. Modifying a const object is UB. The object in question is not const.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: removing `const` is not UB if original data is not `const`, and I don't see how buffer from `std::string` could be `const`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The pointer is returned by a method from the standard library and is declared `const`. It is true that in all common implementations the object is not const, but according to the standard, and before C++17, nothing allows to remove the qualifier.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Seriously?  And how do you reconcile that with `&str[0]` being a non-const pointer to the very same buffer? The object is guaranteed not to be const. The core rules of the language still apply, even to pointers returned from library types, ergo, no UB.

Comment: @Jarod42: I agree that I am nitpicking here, but the library could expect the buffer not be be changed, and later reuse a cached version. Coming for old K&R C I am now frightened by optimizing compilers and very cautious for constness and strict aliasing.

Comment: @StoryTeller Serge is correct that _"Modifying the character array accessed through the const overload of data has undefined behavior."_ according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) and [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.accessors-3).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - I found no reference to that in the standard, so cppreference saying that is news to me. You'll pardon me not trusting a wiki on it.

Comment: @StoryTeller See my edit. (Although I don't know if C++11 was worded differently).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Oaky, n569 says it too. But it's lumped under `c_str`, which had historic reasons to say it. This feels like a wording defect.

Comment: (For completeness, here is the C++11 wording: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/string.ops#string.accessors-3)

Comment: Still a comment because unrelated to original question, but draft n3337 has a requirement in 21.4.7.1 basic_string accessors [string.accessors] that declares both  `c_str` and `data`: §3 *3 Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - You are right. I once segfault-ed because I used `data()` and cast-away the `const`. The string was 1 character test vector in a self test suite, and GCC optimized and put it in a register instead of making it an array of bytes. The self test did something like `char* ptr = s.data(); ptr[0] ^= 1;` to tamper with a byte to see if an HMAC would detect the tampering.

Comment: Another example of UB: if `std::string` uses copy-on-write, then `data()` will not perform a copy, but `operator[]` will.  (Granted, implementations have moved away from COW, but the standard pre C++17 doesn't require that.)

Answer (score 7):

The code is unnecessary, considering that

```
std::string receive_data(const Receiver& receiver) {
    std::string buff;
    int size = receiver.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        buff.assign(receiver.data(), size);
    }
    return buff;
}
```

will do exactly the same.

Comment: You can cut even more code; the `if` is also unnecessary. `assign` will be a no-op then. But continue to unnecessary remove code, and you end up with Jarod42's answer. _None_ of these lines are necessary, as `std::string` already has an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @MSalters I prefer not to assume things that are not given. What if `receiver.size()` can return negative values?

Comment: That would be rather unexpected, given that sizes are typically a `size_t` and therefore unsigned. That does show a possible problem with your code: it might suffer from signed integer overflow, which is undefined behavior. And that's on a code path which handles input, so this may constitute an externally exploitable vulnerability.

Comment: @MSalters True, Jarod42's changes could introduce an externally exploitable vulnerability. They could also introduce crashes if `receiver.data()` is UB when `receiver.size()` is zero.

Answer (score 5):

The big optimization opportunity I would investigate here is: `Receiver` appears to be some kind of container that supports `.data()` and `.size()`.  If you can consume it, and pass it in as a rvalue reference `Receiver&&`, you might be able to use move semantics without making any copies at all!  If it’s got an iterator interface, you could use those for range-based constructors or `std::move()` from `<algorithm>`.

In C++17 (as Serge Ballesta and others have mentioned), `std::string::data()` returns a pointer to non-const data.  A `std::string` has been guaranteed to store all its data contiguously for years.

The code as written smells a bit, although it’s not really the programmer’s fault: those hacks were necessary at the time.  Today, you should at least change the type of `dst_ptr` from `const char*` to `char*` and remove the cast in the first argument to `memcpy()`.  You could also `reserve()` a number of bytes for the buffer and then use a STL function to move the data.

As others have mentioned, a `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` would be a more natural data structure to use here.

Answer (score 4):

One downside is performance.
The .resize method will default-initialize all the new byte locations to 0.
That initialization is unnecessary if you're then going to overwrite the 0s with other data.

Answer (score 1):

I do feel `std::string` is a legitimate *contender* for managing a "buffer"; whether or not it's the best choice depends on a few things...

### Is your buffer content textual or binary in nature?

One major input to your decision should be whether the buffer content is *textual* in nature.  It will be less potentially confusing to readers of your code if `std::string` is used for textual content.

**`char` is not a good type for storing bytes.**  Keep in mind that the C++ Standard leaves it up to each implementation to decide whether `char` will be signed or unsigned, but for generic black-box handling of binary data (and sometimes even when passing characters to functions like `std::toupper(int)` that have undefined behaviour unless the argument is in range for `unsigned char` or is equal to `EOF`) you *probably* want unsigned data: why would you assume or imply that the first bit of each byte is a sign bit if it's opaque binary data?

Because of that, it's undeniably somewhat **hackish to use `std::string` for "binary" data**.  You could use `std::basic_string<std::byte>`, but that's not what the question asks about, and you'd lose some inoperability benefits from using the ubiquitous `std::string` type.

### Some potential benefits of using std::string

Firstly a few benefits:

- it sports the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) semantics we all know and love
- most implementations feature short-string optimisation (SSO), which ensures that if the number of bytes is small enough to fit directly inside the string object, dynamic allocation/deallocation can be avoided (but there may be an extra branch each time the data is accessed)

  - this is perhaps more useful for passing around copies of data read or to be written, rather than for a buffer which should be pre-sized to accept a decent chunk of data if available (to improve throughput by handling more I/O at a time)
- there's a wealth of `std::string` member functions, and non-member functions designed to work well with `std::string`s (including e.g. `cout << my_string`): if your client code would find them useful to parse/manipulate/process the buffer content, then you're off to a flying start
- the API is very familiar to most C++ programmers

### Mixed blessings

- being a familiar, ubiquitous type, the code you interact with may have specialisations to for `std::string` that better suit your use for buffered data, *or those specialisations might be worse*: do evaluate that

### Concerned

As Waxrat observed, what is lacking API wise is the ability to grow the buffer efficiently, as `resize()` writes NULs/'\0's into the characters added which is pointless if you're about to "receive" values into that memory.  This isn't relevant in the OPs code where a copy of received data is being made, and the size is already known.

### Discussion

Addressing einpoklum's concern:

> `std::string` was not intended for use as a buffer; you would need to double-check the description of the class to make sure there are no "gotchas" which would prevent certain usage patterns (or make them trigger undefined behavior).

While it's true that `std::string` wasn't originally intended for this, the rest is mainly FUD.  The Standard has made concessions to this kind of usage with C++17's non-`const` member function `char* data()`, and `string` has always supported embedded zero bytes.  Most advanced programmers know what's safe to do.

### Alternatives

- static buffers (C `char[N]` array or `std::array<char, N>`) sized to some maximum message size, or ferrying slices of the data per call
- a manually allocated buffer with `std::unique_ptr` to automate destruction: leaves you to do fiddly resizing, and track the allocated vs in-use sizes yourself; more error-prone overall
- `std::vector` (possibly of `std::byte` for the element type; is widely understood to imply binary data, but the API is more restrictive and (for better or worse) it can't be expected to have anything equivalent to Short-String Optimisation.
- Boost's `small_vector`: perhaps, if SSO was the only thing holding you back from `std::vector`, and you're happy using boost.
- returning a functor that allows lazy access to the received data (providing you know it won't be deallocated or overwritten), deferring the choice of how it's stored by client code

Answer (score 1):

use C++23's `string::resize_and_overwrite`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite

https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1072r10.html

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] static inline string formaterr (DWORD errcode) {
    string strerr;
    
    strerr.resize_and_overwrite(2048, [errcode](char* buf, size_t buflen) {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage
        return FormatMessageA(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            nullptr,
            errcode,
            0,
            buf,
            static_cast<DWORD>(buflen),
            nullptr
        );
    });
    
    return strerr;
}
```