# Why do strings in a std::vector<std::string> end up with the same data address?

Tags: c++

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(2, std::string(24,0));
    for (auto& s : v) {
        std::cout << "Address: " << (void*)s.data() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/D84Bxz)

I would expect each string in the vector to point to a different memory region, but with both gcc 6.3.0 and 8.2.1 when compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, they show the same address. (when compiling without the flag, they show different addresses). Why is that?

Comment: I haven't investigated this, but try putting strings with **different text** into the vector.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: @PeteBecker: It is now. I took the time to edit this since it's not something I would have expected, even with the "as-if" rule.

Comment: @JeJo Aha.  I needed to change `-std=c++17` to `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @sunmat Nice question. Why did you pick that particular std::string construction?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm sure you know this but this `std::vector` constructor changes as from C++17 with the `pmr` stuff.

Comment: @Bathsheba I had actually forgotten about it.  It's not a feature I use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` <sup>(1)</sup> with this `std::string` uses COW strategy which was allowed pre C++11.

**C**opy **O**n **W**rite is an optimization strategy. With COW when multiple `std::strings` objects are constructed with the same value only one underlying string array would be created and all objects would point to it. This is what you observe in your code. When writing to one of the objects a copy of the string array unique to that `std::string` object would be created and then that would be modified.

Since C++11 this strategy is illegal <sup>(2)</sup> and most implementations now use SSO (Short String Optimization) optimizations for `std::string` instead.

---

(1) [Understanding GCC 5's _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI or the new ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571583/understanding-gcc-5s-glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-or-the-new-abi)

(2) [Legality of COW std::string implementation in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11)